# SKStoreReviewController requestReview doesn't prompt for review

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I want to use the new feature added in 10.3 to ask users for reviews. In the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview?language=objc), apple states that when this method is called "a rating/review request view is displayed".

I am getting the rating view( where you can select how many stars to rate), but I am not able to write a review. I have to mention that I only tested in simulator.

Is this the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In development mode the “Submit” button is disabled. Once your app is in the App Store, this button becomes active and the user is given the option to write a review after they hit “Submit”.

Comment: Tell me where you read this information about the inactive button. My application already exists in the AppStore, and I wanted to update it for iOS10, but the button is also not active.

Comment: It is explained in the requestView() Quick Help description note.

Answer (score 6):

On development mode it always displays the prompt but doesn't actually do anything.

If you want to point people to write a review about your app:

> To automatically open a page on which users can write a review in the
>   App Store, append the query parameter action=write-review to your
>   product URL.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview?language=objc).

EDIT: The comment below is correct.

Comment: The above answer is correct, additionally keep in mind that you won't even see the modal when distributing via TestFlight.

Comment: I was talking about writing a review, not rating. If the application is released, is it possible to write a review (e.g. "This application is really useful") from the prompt?

Comment: @Vaiden - Thank you for your answers. I understand that that is one way to do it. Moreover apple says **"In addition, you can continue to include a persistent link "**, so what you said is an alternative that opens the itunes url of the application( same behaviour as in the past ).

I am more curious about this "reviewRequest" functionality. It says it can show a rating/review request. Does apple consider rating (eg. 4 stars) same thing as a review?

Comment: @RaduCarlig this seems to be a new question, and also one that deals with speculations. I would suggest opening a new thread