# SKStoreReviewController requestreview not showing alert in simulator iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had implemented `[SKStoreReviewController requestreview]` in a sample application and I can see the alert with stars and cancel and submit button. If I implement the same in my current application it is not showing up anything. Why is it not working in my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SKStoreReviewController requestReview doesn't prompt for review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068925/skstorereviewcontroller-requestreview-doesnt-prompt-for-review)

Comment: This covers requests in detail & should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057452/why-the-skstorereviewcontroller-does-not-let-me-submit-a-review/45061556#45061556

Comment: i know that submit button will be disabled.but the problem is rating view itself not showing when application is launched in simulator.

Comment: @sampath Make sure simulator's iOS version >= 10.3. SKStoreReviewController is supported from iOS 10.3

Comment: @trungduc i checked and simulator version is 11.4. Even I installed the application in physical device ,but still I cannot see rating view.

Comment: @sampath Try to call `[SKStoreReviewController requestreview]` in a new project and it works as expected. Maybe problem is in another place.

Comment: @trungduc As posted above it is working as expected if I make new project.I checked the logs in my application and I am recieving this error .                                    **Warning: Attempt to present <SKStoreReviewViewController: 0x7fb2436f5120> on <UIApplicationRotationFollowingController: 0x7fb2434ce710> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**